# What exactly does "common-mode" mean in the context of op-amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode

I read [this article](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/linear_opamp/what-is-the-common-mode-input-voltage-of-an-op-amp.html) about common-mode and rail-to-rail op-amps.

For the common-mode, does the op-amp need to be configured in feedback mode such as a non-inverting amplifier?

[image]

Should it be configured as an inverting amplifier? (Otherwise not common-mode)

[image]

Is a comparator common-mode?

[image]

Is a fully differential amplifier common-mode?

[image]

Comment: That article talks about the common-mode input voltage of an opamp, that is, the signal that is common to both the inverting and noninverting terminals (which is ideally rejected).

Comment: OK! So does the *Common-mode* just means common noise can be eliminated due to the op-amp feature: (V+) - (V-) ?

Comment: Any common noise or signal, yes.  An ideal opamp completely rejects all common mode inputs, but real opamps have a limited ability to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first line of the article states: common mode voltage is simply the range where if both inputs are within, then the rest of the data sheet still applies accurately. Outside of that range, the op-amp may not behave quite as the rest of the data sheet states. The easiest example of this is gain. In normal operation, an op-amp has extremely high gain, but if you go outside of common mode voltage range, then the gain will start degrading/decreasing rapidly.

The topology you choose and the specific voltage of your input signals will determine whether or not you're in "common-mode" input range at a given time.

Most, or maybe all, topologies could end up outside of common mode voltage ranges at some specific time. What is important is to understand under what conditions will you be outside of the common-mode voltage range when designing a circuit, and if so will the op-amp you choose still suffice for your application?

Answer (score 4):

The "common mode" of a differential amplifier is the average  ground-referenced voltage of the two input signals.

Let's take a typical load cell as an example. These devices are made of variable-resistance strain gauges in a bridge configuration. You apply an excitation voltage at one end, and ground at the other, and under no load, both sensor leads output exactly half the excitation voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA3tdr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Under load, though, the variable resistors change resistance, producing a "differential" (read: "different") voltage on each of the two output wires. Now, instead of 5.000 V on both, we have one at 4.975 V and one at 5.025 V.

But the average voltage of the two is still 5 V, and more importantly, we don't care about that. The signal of interest is the *difference* between the two sides, i.e. 5.025 V - 4.975 V = 50 mV. So we use a differential amplifier to take the difference (and probably multiply it by some gain factor).

Unfortunately, real amplifiers don't simply take the difference of two signals. Different average ("common-mode") voltages will have an effect on the output. In the ideal case, input voltages of 10.025 and 9.975 should still produce 50 mV at the output, but in reality they will produce a slightly different value from our 5.025 and 4.975 example. How different? That's determined by the common-mode rejection ratio (CMRR) of the amp. For example, if a differential input change of \$Y\$ volts produces a change of 1 V at the output, and a common-mode change of \$X\$ volts produces a similar change of 1 V, then the CMRR is \$X/Y\$. Often you'll see this expressed in decibels, and quality modern op-amps can have ratios in the 100-150 dB range.

Amplifiers will also be specified with a minimum and maximum input voltage, as referenced to ground, that can be applied to any one pin. If your common-mode voltages exceed this spec, the amplifier will not function properly. For example, even though they're still only 50 mV different, applying 200.025 V and 199.975 V will probably not have acceptable results.

In general, differential amplifiers are designed to reject as much of the common-mode voltage as possible, and amplify only the differential voltage.

Answer (score 1):

When every point in a circuit has the same phase and magnitude relationship to a ground referenced source, then the source is considered common mode. We say that the circuit is “floating” on the common mode signal. We also say that every point in the circuit is “balanced to earth”, “balanced to ground” or “balanced to the common mode signal”.

If one region of the circuit is “out of balance”, then a differential signal is created from the common mode one resulting in noise and interference.

For operational amplifier circuits, the conversion from common-mode to differenial mode occus at the two inputs. If these inputs are balanced to the common mode source then the common mode signal will not be amplified.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj5rw9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The figures above show the common mode valtage (CMV) as it applies to operational amplifiers. The CMV is amplified by both the inverting path and the non inverting path with the results adding together.

The non-inverting gain is 2, while the inverting gain is -1. So the CMV is amplified by 1 thus appearing on the output. The output is usually referenced to the point of application of the common mode signal as shown by the voltmeters. THe voltmeters display the difference between its two terminals, so the common mode voltage is subtracteed to zero, leaving the differential mode voltage to be displayed.

> Is a fully differential amplifier common-mode?

No. They are opposite definitions. $$V_{CM}=\frac{V_P+V_M}{2}, V_{DIFF}=V_P-V_M$$

For operational amplifiers with a differential output the subtraction is applied internally, then the result is presented differentially to the output.

The quality of the balance to ground throughout the circuit determines the level of common mode rejection. While the amplifier is specified with a certain capability it is upto the designer and layout artist to maximize balance.